# How To Insert PHP Variable into IF MySQL Row1=Row2 Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is the code I have now:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">
        <?php 
        // IF the users tips match with the correct tip, echo correct, else wrong on table cell
        if ($row['1g1']==$row['1w1']){
        ?>          
            <img src="../../images/tick-cross/Tick1.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Correct" border="0" />
        <?
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <img src="../../images/tick-cross/Cross1.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Wrong" border="0" />
        <?
        }
        ?>
        </td>
```

Basically, if 2 rows in the table are equal it inserts a image of a tick/check, if they arent it inserts an image of a cross.

if your confused [view the table here](http://pddtest2.fhost.com.au/tables/selections/round1.php)

Ok so I want to make the numbers before the 'g' and the 'w' into variables because i would otherwise have to change them hundreds of times.
IN THE Line:

```
if ($row['1g1']==$row['1w1']){
```

I want to make it:`if ($row['$VARIABLEg1']==$row['$VARIABLEw1']){`

What is the correct syntax of doing this? its driving me insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is done by adding curly braces around the variable like so:

```
$row["{$VARIABLE}g1"] == $row["{$VARIABLE}w1"]){
```

Btw, it only works inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($row[$VARIABLE . "g1" ]==$row[$VARIABLE . "w1"]) {
```

This should work